# Error Testing smart contract with truffle for Solidity Ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

*i have to test smart contract*

**File ApprovalContract**

```
const ApprovalContract = artifacts.require( "../../contracts/ApprovalContract.sol");

 contract("ApprovalContract", function (accounts) {
it("initiates contract", async function () {
const contract = await ApprovalContract.deployed();
const approver = await contract.approver.call();
assert.equal(
  approver,
  0x8c4b9b5262f1ae1bdfb58f6579348817c4da4277,
  "approvers don't match"
);
});
it("takes a deposit", async function () {
const contract = await ApprovalContract.deployed();
  await contract.deposit(accounts[0], { value: 1e18, from: accounts[1] });
  assert.equal(
  await web3.eth.getBalance(contract.address),
  1e18,
  "amount did not match"
);
});
it(
"makes the transaction when approved, approver: " + accounts[2],
async function () {
  const contract = await ApprovalContract.deployed();
  const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(contract.address);
  await contract.deposit(accounts[0], { value: 1e18, from: accounts[1] });
  await contract.approve({ from: accounts[2] });
  assert.equal(
    web3.eth.getBalance(contract.address),
    0,
    "didn't transfer ether"
  );
  }
);
 });
```

truffle compile,truffle migrate run successfully.

> when i run the command "truffle test" i have this error :
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Without the function in your .sol contract I can't be 100% sure, but your Approval event is probably being emitted incorrectly inside of your **accept** method.

Take a look at how the **accept** function's being used in the 2nd example here:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.1/types.html?highlight=approve#mapping-types

```
emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
```